# Python "table" or "matrices" project

Tags: python, project

I need a a advice for my code. At school we are learning how to do tables with python.
I am trying to complete the inverse diagonal with "1" but I can't figure it out how to do it !

```
nbr_co = int(input("number of columns : "))
grid = [[0]*nbr_co for i in range(nbr_li)]

def affiche(grid):
    for i in range(nbr_li):
        print(grid[i])

for i in range():
    grid[i][] = 1
    grid[][i] = 1
affiche(grid)
```

Here is the kind of output :

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
nbr_co = int(input("number of columns : "))
nbr_li = int(input("number of lines: "))
grid = [[0]*nbr_co for i in range(nbr_li)]


def affiche(grid):
    for i in range(nbr_li):
        print(grid[i])

for i in range(nbr_co):
    grid[i][i] = 1
affiche(grid)
```

And if you want the other diagonal, do it like this:

```
nbr_co = int(input("number of columns : "))
nbr_li = int(input("number of lines: "))
grid = [[0]*nbr_co for i in range(nbr_li)]


def affiche(grid):
    for i in range(nbr_li):
        print(grid[i])

for i in range(nbr_co):
    grid[i][(nbr_co - 1) - i] = 1
affiche(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do.
First of all, if you want to manipulate the inverses of a diagonal matrix, the number of rows and columns must be the same.

In the example below you will find an example of what you are trying to do.

```
nbr_column = 4 #you can chose any number you want.
grid = []  # it's your table.
for i in range(nbr_column):
    row = [] # this variable will present a row of your table.
    for j in range(nbr_column):
        row.append(0)
    grid.append(row)

""" to display your table"""
for i in grid:
    print(i)

""" to change diagonal with 1 """
for i in range(len(grid)):
    grid[i][i] = 1

""" to display your new table"""
for i in grid:
    print(i)
```